# Force to change library in Java

Tags: java, libraries, jmonkeyengine

I am using the library Quaternion (jMonkey) in Java which I have imported as external jar files.

Lately, I tried to use another library also called Quaternion. The problem is that since I imported this library e.g "Import com.etc.etc.Quaternion;" even if I have commented out the part where it is imported the compiler doesn't recognise the methods of the initial library (jMonkey) wich was imported as jar.

How can I define that the methods are from the external jar jMonkey library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution, it was pretty stupid.

The part where the libraries where imported was not expanded and for some reason the only library showing was the one that I didn't want to use.
Expanded this part of code, uncommented the jMonkey library and done!

Comment: Good you found your solution, as an added piece of information you can also use a class's long name when naming conflicts occur, for example `com.jme3.math.Vector3f test=new com.jme3.math.Vector3f(1,2,3);`

Comment: Thanks I think this might come in handy.